Django rest framework trae información incompleta en consulta
Tengo un detalle al realizar la consulta con django rest framework,
la consulta se realizara correctamente, pero la información es incompleta
ya que en las serializaciones tengo implementado una relación anidada con otro serialización.
models.py
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='nombres')
    active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='activo', default=True )

    class Meta:
        db_table="contact"

class ContactPhoneNumbers(models.Model):
    tel = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='telefono')
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        db_table='contact_phone_numbers'

serializer.py
class ContacPhoneNumberstSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=ContactPhoneNumbers
        fields = ['tel']

class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contact_phone = ContacPhoneNumberstSerializer(many=True, read_only=True) # relacion anidada

    class Meta:
        model=Contact
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'contact_phone']
        read_only_fields = ['id']

Response body
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "nuevo"
  }
]

Tengo implementado swagger y en la visualización del ejemplo si mapea correctamente como debería traer la consulta


Pude encontrar el detalle del porque no se visualizaba toda la información en la consulta, lo que realice fue agregar en el modelo el nombre de la relación.
Model.py
class ContactPhoneNumbers(models.Model):
    tel = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='telefono')
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name='contact_phone', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

